# Column Name = %Column Name% SQL

Tags: sql, netezza

We have a class that replaces SQL parameters with their actual HashMap values. For example, select * from x where date = %processingDate% will substitute the value of processingDate and then retrieve the corresponding records. However, it seems to not do the replacement when the parameter name is the same name as the column; for example, select * from x where date = %date% does not substitute date and then retrieves all the records because it's acting like an always true boolean. Is this expected SQL behavior?

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Given date is a reserved keyword in T-SQL I would recommend wrapping the column with [] to qualify the column.

Link to list of reserved kewords
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/reserved-keywords-transact-sql

You mentioned SQL Paramater in your question. I would expect your parameter to look like @date if it is a sql parameter. If it does not have the @ prefix your query may be evaluating the column and not the parameter that you expect.

I believe something like this would work for you:

--Assuming @date is being evaluated as a string
SELECT *
FROM x
WHERE [date] LIKE '%' + @date + '%'

--Evaluates the specific value (Research differences between like and = operator)
SELECT *
FROM x
WHERE [date] = @date

Comment: Date was a bad example. It's actually something completely different in our case, which is definitely not a reserved word. Specifically, y = %y% is returning all records if y is a column in table x is the case we are debugging.

Comment: I guess this is more a question for the programming language you have implemented the 'replace' functionality in.

Comment: I would recommend looking at the resulting sql in the plan files or catalog views